# modified value in form_state but it is not being saved

Tags: forms

in the validation of my form i pass the form_state by reference and I modified the form state value of one of the fields with `$form_state['values']['field_total_payment']['und'][0]['value'] = $total_payment;`

I also tried  `form_set_value($form['field_total_payment'], array('und' => array(0 => array('value' => $total_payment))), $form_state);`

and I add a second submit to check if the value is there and I can see that with both pieces of code it is in the form_state['value'] , but it is not getting saved to the node.

What is missing for this information to be stored into the database?

Comment: Have you made sure your form validation function definition is passing `$form_state` by reference, not by value?

Comment: Yes it is passing it by reference

Comment: Would be good to post the whole code to have a full picture of the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

update, i took off the submit handler that i had added to look at the data and it works now.

Comment: I am not sure if this post completely answers the original question, but glad to see you've figured it out. If you update the question with your submit callback you might get a better answer on what was wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
$form_state->setValue($key, $value);
```

In your case, that should be

```
$form_state->setValue(['field_total_payment'], $total_payment);
```

Comment: no that gives this error "Fatal error: Call to a member function setValue() on array in /Users/dcastillo/Sites/devdesktop/awards-dev/docroot/sites/all/modules/custom/application_editing/application_editing.module on line 291

Comment: I was assuming you are using Drupal 8. However, as your $form_state is an array and not an object, that was probably wrong.